# Complex manifold with non-finitely generated canonical ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

P.M.H. Wilson has an example of a compact non-Kahler manifold whose canonical ring is not finitely generated; see [his article](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CM_1981__43_3_365_0) and [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87860/example-of-a-compact-kahler-manifold-with-non-finitely-generated-canonical-ring). I'm trying to understand his construction and have trouble understanding how he conludes that his ring is not finitely generated.

I'll briefly describe his construction. First, Wilson fabricates a projective surface $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$ with a divisor $D$ such that the ring
$$
R(\widetilde{\mathbb{P}} ,D) := \bigoplus_{m \geq 0} H^0(X,mD)
$$
is not finitely generated by following ideas of Zariski: Let $C \subset \mathbb P^2$ be an elliptic curve and $H$ a line. Blow up 12 points in general position on $C$ and a point outside of $C$ to get $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$. Let $C'$ be the proper transform of $C$, $E$ the exceptional divisor of the point outside of $C$ and $H' = f^*H - E$. If $D := C' + H'$, then $R(\widetilde{\mathbb{P}},D)$ is not finitely generated.

Second, Wilson makes a double cover $S$ of $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$ ramified over a general element of $|6C' + 6H'|$ and desingularizes to get $\alpha : \tilde S \to \widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$. Then $K_{\tilde S} \sim \alpha^*(2C' + 3H' + E)$.

Third, he makes a nontrivial torus bundle $\pi : W \to \widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$, that is therefore non-Kahler. The fibers are of dimension 2, so $W$ is a fourfold. One remarks that $K_{W / \widetilde{\mathbb{P}}} = \pi^*\mathcal O(-2H')$.

Fourth, take the fibered product $V = W \times_{\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}} \tilde S$ and let $g : V \to \widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$ be the induced morphism. As $\alpha : \tilde S \to \widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$ is finite of degree 2, this is a compact non-Kahler fourfold. We see that $K_V = g^* \mathcal O(2C' + H' + E)$.

Until now, I'm mostly fine with his construction and can either see or am willing to take on faith how each step is necessary. But here Wilson claims that $R(V,K_V)$ is not finitely generated, and I don't see how. I assume there's some link between $R(V,K_V)$ and $R(\widetilde{\mathbb{P}},D)$, but it has escaped me so far. How do we see this?